# Como autocompletar campos al seleccionar un codigo - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

¡Saludos! Tengo un formulario de venta, en el cual necesito que al escribir el codigo del producto dentro de su campo correspondiente, los campos, de nombre y precio, se automcompleten con la información correspondiente que se tiene en la base de datos, y que pertenezcan a ese codigo, pero para ser honesto, no estoy muy seguro de como lograrlo, se que se tendria que lograr mas con la parte de js, agradezco mucho su ayuda, este seria el formulario y mi migración:

**product_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :code %>
    <%= form.text_field :code %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :name %>
    <%= form.text_field :name %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :price %>
    <%= form.text_field :price %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= form.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Product.rb**

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :name
      t.float :price

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

¡Agradezco inmensamente alguien pudiese sacarme de este atolladero!

Answer (score 0):

Para esta funcionalidad que necesitas vas a tener que utilizar javascript y ruby, [select2](https://select2.org) para al momento que teclees una letra pueda ir a la base de datos y traer los valores que necesitas, así mismo necesitarás un endpoint`/model.json` de donde se estarán leyendo tus datos, la implementación es muy sencilla.

Comment: Basicamente Carlo, lo que necesito es como cuando vas al super, pasan el producto, y toma el codigo de ese producto, y automaticamente llama al nombre del producto, y al precio, es decir que al escribir el codigo dentro de un text_field, me debe de llenar al mismo tiempo el text_field de nombre, y de precio

Comment: ¿Tienes una idea de como realizar eso Carlos? Aqui esta mi codigo completo en este otro post, dado que no tuve ninguna respuesta aqui, sin embargo, aun no he encontrado una solución apropiada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52067164/how-to-complete-form-fields-automatically-in-ruby-on-rails/52069808?noredirect=1#comment91122618_52069808

Answer (score 0):

en realidad lo que quieres hacer es sencillo. Te escribo en pasos lo que quieres hacer

1. Capturar el evento con jquery o ES6. (Puede utilizar keyDown o keyUp o change)
2. Es crear un ruta que busque por este codigo.
3. Tu controlador debe retornar un json con la respuesta que son el precio y el nombre.
4. Al solicitar via ajax en tu callback success o como lo manejes lo que haces es rellenar la informacion en los inputs

Comment: Saludos Alexei! Tienes algun ejemplo? No importa lo sencillo que sea agradezco tu ayuda